# Ruuning external jar on talend

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea, talend

I have created a java program which just displays some messages.
And created its .jar file. I want to put that jar file on talend.
I did it using the tlibrary component. But now how do I run it.
I tried connecting it to other components like tjavarow.

The jar simply has a code which displays hello world.
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Create a routine in the code tab in talend
Right click on the routine to edit the routine libraries and add your jar.

call this routine in the tJava.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Trigger after tlibraryload component. At first configure tlibraryload with .jar file path. Then you need to execute OnSubjobOk from tlibraryLoad to starting component of other Job which you want to execute that use loaded Jar.